# How to remove string characters except first in java

Tags: java, string

In java, I have a String:

```
James May, Jack Jones
```

I would like to remove the characters except first and add dot.
Retrun should looks like `J. May, J. Jones`

How would I do this?

I have tried this

```
for (int i=1; i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if (i%2==0)
        {
            dot=str.replaceAll("[a-z]", ".");
            jTextArea2.setText(dot);
        } 
    }
```

But it replace all lower case charatcers

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: why it won't remove the `May` substring?

Comment: There are many easy approaches to this. What have you tried? Why did it fail? What inputs did you test it for? What outputs did you get? What happened when you debugged?

Comment: @AvinashRaj In English it's sometimes common to abbreviate a person's name in this manner. Something like J.K. Rowling, for example. That's my best guess.

Comment: Please update your post with what you have tried to do.

Comment: `System.out.println("James May".replaceFirst("(?<=^.)\\S+", "."));`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, I have updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alternatively use this, that works like you want

```
String a = "James May";
String[] b = a.split(" ");
String c = b[0].charAt(0) + ". ";
for (int i = 1; i < b.length; i++) {
    c += b[i] + " ";
}
System.out.println(c);
```

Or if you want something that makes it multiple times use:
(Credit to Avinash Raj)

```
String a = "James May, Jack Jones, Jaime Martinez";
String[] b = a.split(", ");
String c = b[0].replaceFirst("(?<=^.)\\S+", "."); 
for(int i = 1; i < b.length; i++) {
c += ", " + b[i].replaceFirst("(?<=^.)\\S+", ".");
}
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I enter the string from keyboard and this works only for 1st name.

For exaple i type "James May, Jack Jones, ... " and this give me "J. May, Jack Jones, ..."

Comment: This is what did i want. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class and adapt it to your own java code assuming you keep the original string in the format of `"FirstName LastName"` and use `", "` to split the string `"FirstName LastName, FirstName LastName"`.

```
public class StringEditor
{
    String editMe = "James May, Jack Jones";

    public void runStringEdit()
    {
        String edit1 = editMe.replaceAll(",", "");
        System.out.println("After step one: "+edit1);
        String[] edit2 = edit1.split(" ");

        for(int i =0; i<edit2.length; i++)
        {
            int correctNum = i+1;
            System.out.println("After part "+correctNum+" of step 2: "+edit2[i]);
        }

        for(int i =0; i<edit2.length; i++)
        {
            int correctNum = i+1;
            if(correctNum%2!=0)
            {
                edit2[i]=edit2[i].charAt(0)+". ";
                System.out.println("After part "+correctNum+" of step 3: "+edit2[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if(!edit2[correctNum].equals("")) //Stops "," being added to last surname by causing a null pointer exception in the if statement
                    {
                        edit2[i]=edit2[i]+", ";
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }

                System.out.println("After part "+correctNum+" of step 3: "+edit2[i]);
            }
        }

        String finalEdit = "";

        for(int i =0; i<edit2.length; i++)
        {
            int correctNum = i+1;
            finalEdit = finalEdit+edit2[i];
        }

        System.out.println("After final step: "+finalEdit);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringEditor sE = new StringEditor();
        sE.runStringEdit();
    }
}
```

The final output of using this class will be `FirstName Intial. LastName, FirstName Intial. LastName` which will equal `J. May, J. Jones` in this case.

The actual output shows how the program did it step by step and will look like this;

[image: Outputs to console from code]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it not very flexible but it works for what you want to do, I think.

```
String a = "James May";
String[] c = a.split("\\s+");
String b = c[0].substring(0, 1) + ". " + c[1].substring(0, c[1].length());  
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, but I need to do it more times. Like if input is "James May, Jack Jones..."

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
    String str = "James May";
    String abr = 
            str.substring(0, 1)//get the first character
            +". "// add a dot and space
            +str.split(" ")[1];//get the last name
```

EDIT: looping through an array

```
for(String str : arrayOfNames){
    String str = "James May";
    String abr = 
            str.substring(0, 1)//get the first character
            +". "// add a dot and space
            +str.split(" ")[1];//get the last name
            //do something with abr
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, but I need to do it more times. Like if input is "James May, Jack Jones..."

Comment: check the edit. not sure how you planned on storing your list of names